# Ubuntu software is not working, upgraded from 15 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu today to 16.04 LTS, everything went fine. But somehow Ubuntu software is not working.
by not working I mean:

- The windows opens and I see the `Transmission` app as featured
- I go to other Tabs and nothing is shown
- I search for an app and it just keeps spinning without showing any error msg or any result
- I've checked and I have a working internet connection
- I don't know how to debug or reinstall it

Comment: The Ubuntu software Centre is not supported in 16.04. Use gnome software

Comment: @Motte001, that's the same thing. gnome software is named `ubuntu software` from 16

Comment: `GNOME Software replaces Ubuntu Software Center. This brings a faster store experience and moves our archive metadata in line with Debian. It has been renamed "Ubuntu Software" to improve recognition for Ubuntu Software Center users.`

Comment: didn't know, on xUbuntu it's called only `software`